# How do i send the role name?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

```
    if before.roles != after.roles:
        with open("log.json", 'r') as f:
             ac = json.load(f)
        for key in ac:
          if int(key) == after.guild.id:
       # for key in ac:
              channel = client.get_channel(ac[key])
              #embed = discord.Embed(
              #    colour = COLOR
              #)
              #embed.set_author(name=NAME)
              #embed.set_thumbnail(url=PFP)
              #embed.add_field(name="Old nickname", value=f"{before.display_name}", inline=True)
              #embed.add_field(name="New nickname", value=f"{after.display_name}", inline=True)
              await channel.send(f"{before.roles}, {after.roles}")
              #await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

I just keep getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9xm4.png).

How would I make it show the role that was removed/added without all the other junk?

Comment: You have to parse the "junk" and extract what you want.

Comment: I am new to pythong, What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print just all the role names, then you can use the join function and pass in the roles as the iterable.

For example, the below will send before and after roles, where the roles are joined by a comma:

```
before_roles = ",".join([role.name for role in before.roles])
after_roles = ",".join([role.name for role in after.roles])
await channel.send(f"{before_roles}, {after_roles}")
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do i only print the role that was added/removed?